# AWS Documentation: How is Lambda's response var used in API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am reading [this AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/create-dynamic-contact-forms-for-s3-static-websites-using-aws-lambda-amazon-api-gateway-and-amazon-ses/) to learn how to make my static website's form POST data to API Gateway and Lambda.

Most of it makes sense to me, but the Lambda code provided contains this unused variable:

```
var response = {
 "isBase64Encoded": false,
 "headers": { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'example.com'},
 "statusCode": 200,
 "body": "{\"result\": \"Success.\"}"
 };
```

I believe this is needed (based on [this AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format)), but is it used automatically? Or is the Lambda missing some vital code? For example:

```
callback(null, response)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side note: In the blog post, the integration set up is not the lambda proxy one, but rather lambda custom integration - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html

To the question: I am pretty sure that the post contains a typo in `context.done(err, null);` which should have been `context.done(err, response);`

However as a result this is not an error, as the custom lambda integration response template is just passing through the empty data and the method response is set to 200 with an empty body.

Answer (score 1):

The response object you are referring to needs to be returned back to the client with the structure provides. The code that you are referencing in the AWS article isn't sending any responses back to the client and that is why you are not seeing the response variable implemented anywhere. To complete the handler function you would return that response variable and transforming the body property to what message you intend to send back to your client. Without this return structure, you will get a 502 error on the client.